# Customize how AWS DMS index data into Elastic Search while migrating

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing, autosuggest, aws-dms

I am currently using AWS DMS for creating a migration task to migrate all data from AWS RDS porstgresql aurora into Elastic Search domain.

The problem is the i don't have the ability to customize the indexing that DMS is making while migrating data. It just creating a simple index with the table name as the index name.

I need to make some mappings for the index and make it capable of doing auto suggest and other things.

Anyone knows how can i customize how AWS DMS building the elastic search indices ?

Answer (score 1):

First : Create index with your settings before migration. ( Properties must match with the table).

Second : Create migration task in AWS DMS. Remember , in "Target table preparation mode" section, choose "Do nothing" ( default is "Drop tables on target" that cause of creating new index on target).

Final : start the task.